# How to call properties of parameters in Java

Tags: java, function, object, eclipse-mars

So I am creating a function which takes an `Object` parameter and I need to access the properties of the parameter like so:

```
private double property;
public void func(Object obj) {
    property = obj.prop;
}
```

But every time I try to do this it gives me the error: "'prop' cannot be resolved or is not a field." Is there a "right" way to do this?
I am using Eclipse Mars.2 to edit this code if that helps.

Comment: The quoted code doesn't look like JavaScript. I'm guessing you're writing in another language entirely, Java. I've edited the tags for you.

Comment: `Object` doesn't have a field called `prop`. you may need a cast.

Comment: The problem remains the same, though, doesn't it? @Aomine 'prop' is just an example property of the `Object` obj.

Comment: @Canvas16: No, not at all. JavaScript doesn't use types. This is a type problem.

Answer (score 1):

> So I am creating a function which takes an `Object` parameter and I need to access the properties of the parameter like so

The parameter shouldn't be declared of type `Object`. It should be declared with the name of whatever class this code is in.

**If** you have a good reason for declaring it of type `Object` (for instance, you're overriding `equals`), you'd do a type check and then a cast:

```
if (/*...appropriate type check here...*/) {
    property = ((TheClass)obj).property;
}
```

But again, normally you shouldn't have to do that.

---

Re "appropriate type check here": The appropriate way to check for the type can vary. For instance, in many cases `obj instanceof TheClass` is good enough. But for overriding `equals`, you typically need something more complex, like `this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())`. You use the right tool for the job in the code you're writing.

Comment: *(Oops, if you see `getType` in the above, hit refresh. Obviously meant `getClass`. Some weird mish-mash of Java and C# in my head.)*

Comment: If I declared the argument with a specific class, wouldn't the function then only accept arguments that are instances of that class? I have several objects declared in their own classes and the function should work for all of them.

Comment: @Canvas16: *"If I declared the argument with a specific class, wouldn't the function then only accept arguments that are instances of that class?"* Yes. Which is important, since you want to access information which is specific to that class. *"I have several objects declared in their own classes and the function should work for all of them."* Then look into [coding to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). I recommend you step back from your current task and work through some basic tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

> **Original Answer based on initial question:** 
>   Your syntax is not javascript. Here is what the JS would look like:
>
> ```
> var myObject = {
>     myProperty: 'value',
>     anotherProperty: 'some other value'
> };
>
> function func(obj) {
>    var thisProperty = obj.myProperty;
> }
> ```

***Well... the tags were changed to Java... so the answer also changes...***

Your property variable is a double value which does not have a "prop" property.

Let's say you have an Object like so:

```
public class MyObject {

    private double prop;

    public double getProp() { return this.prop; }

}
```

Instantiate an instance of MyObject

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
myObj.setProp(13.2);
```

The method could look something like this (inside a class for this example):

```
public class MyService {

    private double property;

    public void func(Object obj) {
       if (obj!=null) {
            this.property = obj.getProp();
       } 
    }

}
```

Pass the instance to the method:

```
MyService.func(myObj);
```

Comment: Okay then. Assume I tagged the wrong language. What would the Java look like?

Comment: I'm not calling the 'prop' property on `property`. I'm setting `property` equal to `obj.prop` which is a double value.

Comment: @Canvas16 I've edited the answer to include some example Java code

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. I change the function to take a `String` parameter  and change an `Object` variable to an instance of a different class depending on the value of the `String` parameter.

```
package main;

import creatures.Dune_Wolf;
import creatures.Rock_Jackal;
import creatures.Sandray;
import creatures.Talon_Snake;
import creatures.Wasteland_Wolf;

public class Combat {
    private Object enemy;
    /**
     * Instigates a battle scenario between 'player' and 'enemy'.
     * @param enemy
     */
    public void battle(String Enemy) {
        if (Enemy.equalsIgnoreCase("dune wolf")) {
            enemy = new Dune_Wolf();
        } else if (Enemy.equalsIgnoreCase("rock jackal")) {
            enemy = new Rock_Jackal();
        } else if (Enemy.equalsIgnoreCase("sandray")) {
            enemy = new Sandray();
        } else if (Enemy.equalsIgnoreCase("talon snake")) {
            enemy = new Talon_Snake();
        } else if (Enemy.equalsIgnoreCase("wasteland wolf")) {
            enemy = new Wasteland_Wolf();
        }
    }
}
```